# Cydia - Add sources through command line

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, ssh, cydia

I am able to SSH into my iPhone and update the file `/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.saurik.Cydia/sources.list` with the number of repos, but the file gets reverted as soon as I try to update the repos through the Cydia app.

Is there a way to download/update the Cydia sources through command link. I am basically looking to add multiple sources easily into Cydia.

Comment: Not exactly the way I wanted it to work, but one can use `SmartSourcePrompt` app which copies all the sources from the clipboard. It has been explained [here](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2015/08/smartsourceprompt-provides-a-quick-way-of-adding-multiple-cydia-sources.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Flame](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.aditkamath.flame/) is the tweak you looking for.

`Batch Add: Add multiple sources at once by having them in your clipboard`